# Drawing custom view on SurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-drawable

I have develop a simple game in Android. I would like to draw multiple views with image and text on SurfaceView in background thread. How can I achive this with best performance? A image and text will be changed dynamically for each view and rendered in each frame. I have read about some options:

1. Inflate view from xml, then fill fields with data, convert to bitmap and draw on surfaceview.
2. Use VectorDrawable. But I don't know how to access inner field to change text.

Any advice?

Comment: Please add what you have done so far.

Comment: What do you mean? I am not goiing to add business code here. In UI layer I have prepared custom SurfaceView that works properly with Activty lifecycle, orientation changes etc. I am using RxJava2 and Schedulers to provide threading. Last step is rendering dynamically changed POJO on canvas. That's all.